# What's wrong with maps and selenium (or my code)?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

Help me please. I want to write a code for clicking on the building on the map. If i do it by my hands - it's ok.

https://www.google.com/maps/@57.9155533,59.9697661,18z

I click on the number of building and something is happening. But when I launch the code, map becomes inactive.

After launching

```
ChromeOptions opts = new ChromeOptions();
opts.addArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/100.0.4896.56 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1");
        
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opts);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/@57.9152965,59.9705073,17.58z");
```

I can't press on the number of building. What's wrong with it? I can't do it by code and hands.

Comment: That code just opens map, does not click on anything so it works fine. You would need to add some click() methods, although I don't know if it will be easy with a google maps which is an interactive map and not a standard website.

Comment: Yeah, I did it, just not add in the code. I've found building number's xpath and add click(). But nothing happen. I tried to click to manually. Same result

Comment: As I said, Google maps is a complex interactive app, you are interacting with a canvas element not with building numbers and labels, so I would assume that you will have to use different approach to automate that. Look for google maps specific solutions.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it. By the way I changed user-agent and it helped... Kind of